# Can 10g databases monitor it from 13c Cloud?

Tags: oracle

I am planning to deploy 13c agent on 10g databases , can i able to monitor ? is 13c OEM compatiable for 10g?

$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11 (Tikanga)

Database vesrions :- 10.2.0.3.0 & 10.2.0.4.0

Answer (score 1):

No we can't monitor Oracle 10g databases from 13.4 OEM.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested 13c personally, but I've been using OEM up to 12c for over 15 years and it's always been downward compatible.  We've monitored databases that were three versions behind, and currently monitor one legacy 10g database with 12c.

Also search for the 'Oracle Client / Server Interoperability Support' matrix found on metalink or oracle support.  This shows which clients are compatible with which servers, so you can check if your agents will talk to OEM.